# SAS importing JSON

Tags: json, sas

I need to convert some JSON into a machine friendly format (e.g. CSV, Excel, Stata, SAS), and am using SAS because my file is huge.

An example of an observation:

```
{"business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA", "full_address": "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018", "hours": {"Tuesday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Friday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Monday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}}, "open": true, "categories": ["Doctors", "Health & Medical"], "city": "Phoenix", "review_count": 9, "name": "Eric Goldberg, MD", "neighborhoods": [], "longitude": -111.98375799999999, "state": "AZ", "stars": 3.5, "latitude": 33.499313000000001, "attributes": {"By Appointment Only": true}, "type": "business"}
```

I've been using the approach recommended by http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/296-2013.pdf.

The problem is that not all observations have an identical entries. For example, some observations may be missing "full_address".

As such my sample code is now

```
filename data '(filename)';
data datatest; * defines dataset;
infile data lrecl = 32000 truncover scanover;
input 
    @'"business_id": "' business_id $255. 
    ;

    business_id = substr(business_id,1,index(business_id,'",')-1);


    IF INDEX(_INFILE_,'"full_address":') > 0
    THEN DO;    
        input @'"full_address": "' full_address $255.;      
        full_address = substr(full_address,1,index(full_address,'",')-1);
    END; 
run;
proc print data = work.datatest;
run;
```

The problem is the code seems to skip over every other observation. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I won't close this as duplicate because this shows an interestingly different issue, but this is very closely similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115091/parse-json-object-in-sas-macro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your initial input is going past the full_address (because it's eating up 255 characters).  You can work around this, like so:

```
input 
    @'"business_id": "' business_id $255. +(-254) @
    ;
```

basically resetting the pointer back to the beginning of the field and allowing you to look for the next part.

You can also read this in a different way; if you have SAS 9.3 (I believe), `PROC GROOVY` can be used to read in JSON files in a simpler fashion.  See my answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115091/parse-json-object-in-sas-macro) for more detail.

Comment: Groovy code that is submitted with PROC GROOVY runs as the process owner, and has the same access to resources (file system, network, and so on) as any process owner. Groovy code access to resources can cause problems when SAS code is running inside multiuser servers like the Stored Process Server. To give administrators some control over this functionality, PROC GROOVY runs only if the NOXCMD option is turned off. All SAS servers are shipped with the NOXCMD option turned on. (support.sas.com)