# Importing a single-line json file in SAS

Tags: json, sas

I have data in the following json format:

```
{"metadata1":"val1","metadata2":"val2","data_rows":[{"var1":1,"var2":2,"var3":3},{"var1":4,"var2":5,"var3":6}]}
```

There are some metadata variables at the start, which only appear once, followed by multiple data records, all on the same line. How can I import this into a SAS dataset?

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure this is sufficiently different from [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115091/parse-json-object-in-sas-macro).  I think most JSON files are technically single-line (and that one the solutions would work fine regardless of line count, I think, with very minor modifications).

Comment: I agree that it's similar, but I don't think any of the existing json questions addressed the issue of reading in  metatdata records, or multiple records per line. I also wanted to demonstrate that it is possible to do this sort of thing without using `scan`.

Comment: Metadata records I suppose I see a difference in, though I'm not sure I think your example is really all that good on that regards - can you improve it re: reading them in automatically perhaps?  Otherwise, the "without using scan" bit, perhaps you can answer that on the linked question.  I think that question/answer is still much more useful overall (given the multiple approaches - and there was another before that I think that also had a couple of examples).  In particular, here you have a 'fake' json file - it would be much better with a real-life example.

Comment: Or at least an example that looks like real life.

Comment: I've encountered a json file with this exact structure fairly recently - only the variable names and values have been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*Create json file containing sample data*/
filename json "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\json.txt";
data _null_;
file json;
put '{"metadata1":"val1,","metadata2":"val2}","data_rows":[{"var1":1,"var2":2,"var3":3},{"var1":4,"var2":5,"var3":6}]}';
run;

/*Data step for importing the json file*/
data want;
infile json dsd dlm='},' lrecl = 1000000 n=1;
retain metadata1 metadata2;
if _n_ = 1 then input @'metadata1":' metadata1 :$8. @'metadata2":' metadata2 :$8. @;
input @'var1":' var1 :8. @'var2":' var2 :8. @'var3":' var3 :8. @@;
run;
```

Notes:

- The point for SAS to start reading each variable is set using `@'string'` logic.
- Setting `,` and `}` as delimiters and using `:` format modifiers on the input statement tells SAS to keep reading characters from the specified start point until it's read the maximum requested number or a delimiter has been reached.
- Setting `dsd` on the infile statement removes the double quotes from character data values and prevents any problems from occurring if character variables contain delimiters.
- The double trailing `@` tells SAS to continue reading more records from the same line using the same logic until it reaches the end of the line.
- Metadata variables are handled as a special case using a separate input statement. They could easily be diverted to a single row in a separate file if desired.
- `lrecl` needs to be greater than or equal to the length of your file for this approach to work.
- Setting `n=1` should help to reduce memory usage if your file is very large, by preventing SAS from attempting to buffer multiple input lines.