# Parse JSON object in SAS macro - Part 2 - using OUTPUT function to handle nested values

Tags: json, sas

This question is related to:  [prior question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115091/parse-json-object-in-sas-macro)

I have a JSON file that looks like:

```
    [
      {
        "rxnorm_id": "999999999",
        "drug_name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "plans": [
          {
            "plan_id_type": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "plan_id": "999999999999999",
            "drug_tier": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "prior_authorization": false,
            "step_therapy": false,
            "quantity_limit": false
           },
```

I am able to import every line into SAS that has 'rxnorm_id and drug_name using this code:

```
    >
    filename data url 'http://stg-oh-medicaid.molinahealthcare.com/JSON/Drugs_Molina_Healthcare.json';
    data formularies;
    infile data lrecl = 32000 truncover scanover;
    input   @'"rxnorm_id": "' rxnorm_id $255.
    @'"drug_name": "' drug_name $255.
    @'"plan_id_type": "' plan_id_type $255. 
    @'"plan_id": "' plan_id $255.
    @'"drug_tier": "' drug_tier $255.
    @'"prior_authorization": ' prior_authorization $255.
    @'"step_therapy": ' step_therapy $255.
    @'"quantity_limit": ' quantity_limit $255.;
    rxnorm_id = scan(rxnorm_id,1,'",');
    drug_name = scan(drug_name,1,'",');
    plan_id_type = scan(plan_id_type,1,'",');
    plan_id = scan(plan_id,1,'",');
    drug_tier = scan(drug_tier,1,'",');
    prior_authorization = scan(prior_authorization,1,'",');
    step_therapy = scan(step_therapy,1,'",');
    quantity_limit = scan(quantity_limit,1,'",');
    run;
```

But, I want to pick up all of the values in the 'plans' nest that are in between the rxnorm and drug name values.  Someone suggested using the OUTPUT option in SAS to see the missing rows.  Anyone got a good fix to my code to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of 9.4, the best way to parse JSON in SAS is [using PROC GROOVY](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings14/SAS379-2014.pdf). That is what I recommend. You can also do it with [DS2](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2015/09/28/parse-json-from-sas/). If you are adventurous, and on 9.4m3, you can also use [PROC LUA](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2015/08/03/using-lua-within-your-sas-programs/). That is what I would try, since it allows you to manipulate SAS datasets easily.

That being said, if you can rely on the simple structure of your example, then you can select only the lines that have fields and output them in the format you wanted using regular expressions in data step:

```
data want;
    infile 'c:/tmp/json_snippet.txt';
    length field $20 data $100;
    keep field data;
    retain re;

    input;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        re = prxparse('/"(.*?)": "?(true|false|.*?(?="))/');
    end;

    if prxmatch(re,_infile_); /* grep only matching lines */

    call prxposn(re,1,start,len);
    field = substr(_infile_,start,len);
    call prxposn(re,2,start,len);
    data  = substr(_infile_,start,len);
run;
```

Caveat emptor: A wise person said that when you solve a problem using regular expressions, now you have two problems :). Among the things that can go wrong:

- line breaks
- using `'` instead of `"` for string delimiters
- lengths
- mixed types

Comment: I am not sure how to incorporate your code into mine (sorry for being slow).  I might have to upgrade to SAS 9.4 (on 9.3 right now).  If I do upgrade to 9.4, is Groovy already installed, or do I have to add the package separately?

Comment: The answer above, based on PRX functions, works in any SAS 9. In fact, I tried it with `FILENAME URL` pointing to the json file in your question and it worked fine, and very fast.

PROC GROOVY may require a bit of setup. The [doc](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/68954/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1x8agymll9gten1ocziihptcjzj.htm) says to turn off the `NOXCMD` option. I can run it just fine on my 9.4 production box without any special setup.

Comment: I see, that is pretty nifty.  Is there a modification to make it work with this link instead:  https://www.bcbstx.com/forms/tx/drugs_tx-1.JSON      I am not sure if this gets at your potential issue of 'line breaks'.  I get this error when I try to use the code you supplied:  ERROR: Cannot load SSL support.
Either way, I very much appreciate your help to this point.

Comment: For a start you'd have to join all lines, then split them in commas that are not part of strings. Then a bunch of other things can go wrong. So my advice at that point is just to use the library.

Comment: OK, I will have to get SAS 9.4, then JAVA, then Groovy.  I have some potential Groovy code I have been creating for this.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: Good luck! There is a link to a paper in my answer. There are other sources as well. I did not have to install anything on 9.4.

Comment: so I have been trying a proc Groovy solution.  I have it pretty close, but I cannot get it to handle a second nest with multiple outputs within that nest ("plans" is the nest).  Any ideas for modifying my code?